# how to implement ionRangeSliders dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have implemented [ionRangeSlider](http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html) to show some values to users through sliders. To implement a slider we have to declare a input tag like this,

```
<input type="text" id="range_26" />
```

after that we must call the id of the input tag via jquery to get the slider.

```
$("#range_26").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "single",
  grid: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  postfix: "%",
  onFinish: function(data) {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax content
    });
  }
)};
```

For single instance it works fine. Some times I have to implement more than one slider according to database content to show the values. But this time it won't work because for every input tag we have to call the id of the tag to get the slider.

I'm fetching data to page via ajax (because my case i have to fetch the data via jquery to show the real time data, so i have to do it through jquery,ajax)

```
$.ajax({
url: 'sitePagefunction.php',
type: 'post',
data: { 'sitePageId' : sitepageid },
success:function(data) {
    $('#ul-devices-2').html(data);
)};
```

In sitePagefunction.php i'm echoing (for the demostration purpose i'm just showing the related things only)

```
while(<condition>){

echo   '<div class="inputRange">
          <input type="text" id="range_26" />
        </div>';

}
```

Here you can see if the while condition runs one time than it won't be problem but if this condition runs more than one time that it will be a problem. This while statement running dynamically according to database content. So, I can't say the exact slider counts.

I want create silders dynamically.

How to solve this problem. (I think you may understand what i'm saying. If not please leave a comment below.)

Comment: Why you didn't use `class` instead of `id`?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked.. This slider working only for ids

Comment: I'm afraid, but you're wrong, I used this plugin in my recent project. could you please provide `jsfiddle`?

Comment: I can but how to call php file in jsfiddle?

Comment: No need for your `server-side` logic, I just want to show you, how you can call this plugin multiple times

Comment: here it is..[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ex18m4d/) but ioRangeslider is not working here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap"></div>
```

**JS** *updated*

```
// append html dynamically
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  $('<div><input type="text" class="my-class" data-min="'+ (i * 4) +'" data-max="'+ (i * 8) +'" /></div>')
    .appendTo($('.wrap'));
}

$(".my-class").ionRangeSlider({
  type: "single",  
  grid: true,
  min: $(this).data('min'),
  max: $(this).data('max')  
});
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/RRzOkg)

Comment: thanks.. This is working. but each slider has their own values. how to show them for each slider. there is attribute call `from`. we have to assign it to it. but how?

Comment: Thanks.. its working.. can we defined our own names to `data` attribute?

Comment: NP, sure, [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)

Comment: but here i want to get the value of sensor that assigned to that. But i can get the value of `data-from` cannot get the value of `data-sensor` it says undefined  why is that? `<input type="text" class="my_class_slider" data-from="'.$sensors->value.'" data-sensor="'. $sensors->device_code .'" />` is it correct?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you, what you mean of `sensor `?

Comment: it is just a name. i'm assigning a id to that attribute ex: `data-sensor=65437`

Comment: I'm not PHP guy, but I just copy your code and I found some extra spaces withing that, please copy & use this: `'<input type="text" class="my_class_slider" data-from="'.$sensors->value.'" data-sensor="'.$sensors->device_code.'" />'`. also please tell me, did you have error for `data-from` too?

Comment: it didn't worked..  i can get the value of `data-from` attribute. but i cannot get of the other data attribute that is the problem

Comment: In inspect element tab i can see the value that assigned to `data-sensor` attribute. but when i want alert the value it says undefined

Comment: Please use `jsfiddle` or `codepen` to showing your code.

Comment: Man, you can not get the value like that, the `this` is not `input` anymore. maybe you should read more about `this keyword` in js. I recommended read the plugin's doc for more info about dealing with `onFinish` event.

Comment: then how to get the value?? Please give an idea

Comment: As I said you need to read the documentation, there is couple of ways that you can deal with values, try to check this 2 logs (using `browser's console`): `onFinish:function(e){console.log(e);console.log(this);}`